# Comparing Two Datas in 2 columns

Tags: vba

I am now taking my first course with VBA Excel. I am really new in VBA so perharps, with your help, I will gain knowledge in doing my best in VBA programming.  I need to compare 2 columns. What i need to do is look for the same data and highlight it but what happens, only the same data on the same row are the ones highlighted. The data in different row is ignored. Help me please.

Here is my code code:

```
Sub Compare()
Dim Col1 As Range
Dim Col2 As Range

    Set Col1 = Application.InputBox("Select First Column to Compare", Type:=8)


    If Col1.Columns.Count > 1 Then

      Do Until Col1.Columns.Count = 1

        MsgBox "You can only select 1 column"
        Set Col1 = Application.InputBox("Select First Column to Compare", Type:=8)

      Loop

    End If


    Set Col2 = Application.InputBox("Select Second Column to Compare", Type:=8)


    If Col2.Columns.Count > 1 Then

      Do Until Col2.Columns.Count = 1

        MsgBox "You can only select 1 column"
        Set Col2 = Application.InputBox("Select Second Column to Compare", Type:=8)

      Loop

    End If


  If Col2.Rows.Count <> Col1.Rows.Count Then

    Do Until Col2.Rows.Count = Col1.Rows.Count

      MsgBox "The second column must be the same size as the first"
      Set Col2 = Application.InputBox("Select Second Column to Compare", Type:=8)

    Loop

  End If


  If Col1.Rows.Count = 65536 Then


    Set Col1 = Range(Col1.Cells(1), Col1.Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count))
    Set Col2 = Range(Col2.Cells(1), Col2.Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count))


  End If



  Dim intCell As Long


  For intCell = 1 To Col1.Rows.Count


    If Col1.Cells(intCell) = Col2.Cells(intCell) Then

      Col1.Cells(intCell).Interior.Color = vbYellow
      Col2.Cells(intCell).Interior.Color = vbYellow

    End If
  Next

End Sub
```

Comment: By the way, do you really need VBA? Conditional formatting doesn't solve your problem?